# Programmatically check Cellular Data on/off in iOS12

Tags: ios12

I have an application for which I need the user have several permissions set a particular way (for example Use Location set to "Always").

My programmers are running into issues checking the "Use Cellular Data" permission. They claim there is no API to determine the status of this on a per app basis. I have followed some discussions on SO and that was true in the past. B

My question is, is there still no reliable way to determine whether a user has granted my app the ability to use cellular data?